# Why can (heat-related) energy $E$ be considered as the product of temperature $C$ and thermal capacity $T$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Why can (heat-related) energy $E$ be considered as the product of temperature $T$ and thermal capacity $C$?

I.e.

$$E=CT$$

---

I've seen this definition in one answer to an excercise in a course, but no explanation of the above is given.

Comment: That is how heat capacity $C$ is $\textit{defined}$. Also more properly the equation is written as $\Delta E=C\Delta T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat capacity is the increment in heat you need to increase the system's temperature by one degree, in other words, it measures system's ability to accept energy as heat

$C\equiv\frac{Q}{\Delta T}$

Where $Q$ is the amount of heat absorbed by the system.  The definition makes sense as the more heat you need to apply to a system to increase it's temperature, the higher the heat capacity (it is directly proportional) and the higher the increase in temperature given a fixed $Q$, the lower the heat capacity (inversely proportional). But as I said, it is just an arbitrary definition that turns out to be useful.

It is also useful because it is related with specific heat capacity (which you can usually find tabulated in books)

$C=mC_s$

where $m$ is the mass and $C_s$ is the specific heat capacity of a determined substance.